# Cordova build: Error converting bytecode to dex: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

Error occurs when trying to build cordova app on android with firebase plugin:

cordova-build error : Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
cordova-build error : Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.

Comment: Kindly share your code how you are converting

Answer (score 0):

Firebase plugin version 2.0.5 is required to solve the problem and at least cordova-android version 6.4.0 is required otherwise other errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

I was previously on Cordova-Android 6.3.0 and started experiencing this issue. Upgrading to 6.4.0 was the solution. I also needed to manually install Gradle as it seems that 6.4.0 does not automatically install Gradle.

Don't understand this part too much but using `brew update && brew install gradle` to install fixed the errors for me.